Implementing Boundary Conditions at Infinity in Numerical Method
Suppose I want to numerically solve a differential equation, the analytical solution of which has boundary conditions at infinity, for example
$$
\tag{1} \begin{cases}
u_t - \nabla^2 u = 0 \quad (\mathbf{x},t) \; \mathrm{in} \; \mathbb{R}^2 \times (0, \infty)
\\
u(\mathbf{x}, 0) = \delta(\mathbf{x}),
\end{cases}
$$
which has analytical solution
$$ u(\mathbf{x}, t) = \frac{1}{4\pi t}\exp \biggl(-\frac{\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}}{4t} \biggr). $$
If I'm solving a variant of (1) posed on a closed and bounded subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by some numerical method - say finite differences or finite elements, what boundary conditions should I impose?
The simplest answer would be homogeneous Dirichlet conditions - but this seems to simple. A solution that agrees more with my geometrical intuition would be homogeneous Neumann conditions, but what other condition would I impose to make sure the problem has a unique solution?

The way to approach this numerically is to implement a perfectly matched layer boundary condition. When you are doing a graphical analysis of your numerical solution, you can only do it in a finite spatial domain. The idea is to implement an absorbing layer at all of the infinity spatial ends. Essentially, you send your solution to the imaginary number space, so it doesn't affect the propagation of your solution in the real number space. It is commonly used to solve hyperbolic PDEs but can be also used to solve parabolic PDEs as well (I used this with the finite difference method). I think you might find this helpful.
Also, here is a Wikipedia link, and you can find a lot of examples on YT too.
